# mongoose query with $in property

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');


var FriendSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

requester: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
},
recipient: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
},
});
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

var Friend = mongoose.model('Friend', FriendSchema);

module.exports = Friend;
```

I am trying to query it by using

```
Friend.find({"requester": { $in: [some id value]}},  function(err, fee){

console.log(fee.recipient);

});
```

and having it return the recipient id value..

Any suggestions would really be helpful, thank you.

Comment: after pasting code try "ctrl + k" which puts it in correct format, so that it will be readable.

Answer (score 0):

you can use projection of mongo.db
the structure is like below ,

```
find(condition , requirefield , callback);
```

below is the example in which the **fee** will contain only the **recipient**

```
Friend.find({"requester": { $in: [some id value]}}, { _id : 0 , requester : 0 } ,function(err, fee){

console.log(fee.recipient);

});
```

you can refer https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#projections for more reference.

Comment: Is there a way to just get the id value and not the field name.

Comment: just make the _id: 1 and rest other field 0 in condition. you will get only _id